# C# Parallel.For and non-initialized arrays

Tags: c#, for-loop, task-parallel-library, allocation

The scenario is this one: inside a Parallel.For an array is used in a non-parallel for. All elements of the array are overwritten and thus it is technically unnecessary to allocate and initialize it (which always happens at construction time, as far as I deduce from C# tutorials):

```
float[] result = new float[16384];
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(0,16384,x =>
{
   int[] histogram = new int[32768]; // allocation and initialization with all 0's, no?
   for (int i = 0; i < histogram.Length; i++)
   {
      histogram[i] = some_func(); // each element in histogram[] is written anew
   }
   result[x] = do_something_with(histogram);
});
```

The solution in sequential code is easy: pull the array in front of the outer for loop:

```
float[] result = new float[16384];
int[] histogram = new int[32768]; // allocation and initialization with      
for(x = 0; x < 16384; x++)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < histogram.Length; i++)
   {
      histogram[i] = some_func(); 
   }
   restult[x] = do_something_with(histogram);
}
```

Neither allocation nor futile 0-ing is happening now in the outer loop.
In the parallel version tho, this is surely a bad move, either the parallel processes are trashing each others histogram results or C# is clever enough to lock `histogram` thereby shutting down any parallelism. Allocating a `histogram[16384,32768]` is equally wasteful. What I am trying now is the

```
public static ParallelLoopResult For<TLocal>(
    int fromInclusive,
    int toExclusive,
    Func<TLocal> localInit,
    Func<int, ParallelLoopState, TLocal, TLocal> body,
    Action<TLocal> localFinally
)
```

library construct (function?), but as this is my first try at parallel programming in C#, I am full of doubts. Is the following a correct translation from the sequential case?

```
float[] result = new float[16384];
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For<short[]>(0, 16384, 
                                             () => new short[32768], 
                                             (x, loopState, histogram) =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < histogram.Length; i++)
    {
       histogram[i] = some_func(); 
    }
    result[x] = do_something_with(histogram);
    return histogram;
}, (histogram) => { });
```

Comment: Have you considered writing the results to a ConcurrentBag?  This is a thread safe implementation that I think you are seeking: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @mjwills to clarify: If this code ran on an 32768-core machine, it would need this many versions of a histogram, but parallelism on a smaller scale suggests that I don't allocate the whole bunch if at any point in time I only need a handful which can be disposed immediately.

Comment: One option would be to set the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` for the `Parallel.For`. Then keep a pool of arrays (basically an array of arrays) of the same size as the MaxDop. `Interlocked.Increment` to get a unique ID for each iteration. `iterationID % MaxDop` to get the index to use of the pool. This gives you a small array of arrays (e.g. 8 arrays) rather than needing 16384 of them, with guarantees that only one thread uses it at a time. _To be fair, that is basically the same approach you are using with your `Parallel.For` thread-local solution._

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly your trying to accomplish with this code,  there may be a better way.

Comment: Specifically do you care how many threads are used to process the results?

Comment: @JSteward I have sensor data which is delivered as 15-bit values in a short[16384]. When I get a hold of the data, there are many lines of this matrix (one per timestep, delivered to my machine in a bulk transmission) to be processed and one of the steps is to run a classifier on the histogram over the values in each of the 16384 sensor taps. No, I don't think there is an easier way, I have to touch each of the values at least once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not completely sure on your requirements but let's look at a starting point:

```
public void Original()
{
    float[] result = new float[16384];
    System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(0, 16384, x =>
    {
        int[] histogram = new int[32768]; // allocation and initialization with all 0's, no?
        for (int i = 0; i < histogram.Length; i++)
        {
            histogram[i] = some_func(); // each element in histogram[] is written anew
        }
        result[x] = do_something_with(histogram);
    });
}
```

The inner loop generates a `histogram` while the outer loop takes one `histogram` and uses it to generate a single value in `Results`.

One solution that's easy to manipulate is to do this processing [TPL-Dataflow](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/09/introduction-to-dataflow-part-1.html), this is an abstraction on top of the TPL. To set this up we're going to need some DTO's to pass through dataflow pipeline.

```
public class HistogramWithIndex
{
    public HistogramWithIndex(IEnumerable<int> histogram, int index)
    {
        Histogram = histogram;
        Index = index;
    }
    public IEnumerable<int> Histogram { get; }
    public int Index { get; }
}

public class IndexWithHistogramSize
{
    public IndexWithHistogramSize(int index, int histogramSize)
    {
        Index = index;
        HistogramSize = histogramSize;
    }
    public int Index { get; }
    public int HistogramSize { get; }
}
```

These classes represent your data at various stages of processing. Now let's see the pipeline.

```
public async Task Dataflow()
{
    //Build our pipeline
    var options = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount,
        //This is default but I want to point it out
        EnsureOrdered = true
    };
    var buildHistorgramBlock = new TransformBlock<IndexWithHistogramSize, HistogramWithIndex>(inputData =>
    {
        var histogram = Enumerable.Range(0, inputData.HistogramSize).Select(_ => some_func());
        return new HistogramWithIndex(histogram, inputData.Index);
    }, options);
    var doSomethingBlock = new TransformBlock<HistogramWithIndex, int>(x => do_something_with(x.Histogram.ToArray()), options);

    var resultBlock1 = new ActionBlock<int>(x => Results1.Add(x), options);
    //var resultBlock2 = new ActionBlock<int>(x => //insert into list with index, options);

    //link the blocks
    buildHistorgramBlock.LinkTo(doSomethingBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });
    doSomethingBlock.LinkTo(resultBlock1, new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });

    //Post data
    var histogramSize = 32768;
    foreach (var index in Enumerable.Range(0, 16384))
    {
        await buildHistorgramBlock.SendAsync(new IndexWithHistogramSize(index, histogramSize));
    }

    buildHistorgramBlock.Complete();
    await resultBlock1.Completion;
}
```

The blocks consisting of two `TransformBLocks` and the `ActionBlock` form a pipeline that's linked. The advantage here is that it becomes very easy to change the degree of parallelism, the bounded capacity of each block to introduce back pressure, and many more.

A big note: The `TransformBlocks`, if parallelism is used, i.e. an MDOP >1, then they will output their items in the order they were received. This means if they come in in order they leave in order. You can also turn ordering off with the block option `Ensure Ordering`. This comes into play if you want your items in a particular index without/with particular ordering.

This may seem as a bit of overkill and might be for your project. But I've found this can be very flexible and easy to maintain. Especially when you start adding steps to the processing chain, adding a block is much cleaner than wrapping another for loop around everything.

Here's the rest of boiler plate code for c&p

```
private ConcurrentBag<int> Results1 = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
private int some_func() => 1;
private int do_something_with(int[] i) => i.First();
```

Comment: Thanks for this cool and interesting answer. While I may not adopt it for the particular problem at hand (my for loop is runnnig and thus I can leave the scene :D ) I will surely adapt to this form of parallelism as it is what I too envision as the "right" form. (to my original question "is my code wrong": it looks like you implicitly said "no",correct?)

Comment: Well if the code "works" then i'd say it's not wrong. On the other hand there's always ways to improve the code. My answer just picks a convenient technique, you could use reactive extension, etc. There's many techniques to handle async and current development.

Answer (score 2):

The less you share among tasks and threads, the *easier* it is to parallelize your code.

If you want to reduce allocations you can reuse buffers. This won't only reduce allocations, it will reduce expensive *garbage collections*. Just *don't* store them in thread-local state though, or you'll have to handle allocating, reallocating, clearing them yourself.

`Parallel.ForEach` uses *tasks*, not threads which means the thread that served one task can end up serving something completely unrelated and yet keep a buffer nobody needs. Furthermore, `Parallel.Foreach` can be configured to *recycle* tasks, to .... clean up accumulated state. In this case you'd have to clean up the buffers from the thread state and reinitialize them again.

It's easier and more performant to use a memory/buffer pool to "rent" ready-made buffers and "release" them once you are done with them.

In the past, you could use the [BufferManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.buffermanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) class provides ready-made `byte[]` arrays and is used by WCF to reuse buffers.

A better option nowadays is to use ArrayPool from the [System.Buffers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Buffers/) package, which can return arrays of any type:

```
var pool = ArrayPool<int>.Shared;
var bufferLength = 32768;

var result = new float[16384];
Parallel.For(0,16384,x =>
{
   try
   {
       var histogram = pool.Rent(bufferLength);
       for (int i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++)
       {
          histogram[i] = some_func(); 
       }
       result[x] = do_something_with(histogram);
    }
    finally
    {
       //Ensure the buffer is returned even in case of error
       pool.Return(histogram);
    }
});
```

The size you specify is the *minimum* one. The pool could return a larger one if there are no buffers available that match the request, which is why you have to use `bufferLength` in the loop.

Using the shared pool should be OK in most cases. Its default maximum array size is 1MB (1 048 576) and 50 arrays per size bucket. ArrayPool organizes buffers of the same size in buckets for faster access.

If you need to, you can create another pool a specifix maximum buffer size. When you create an array you can specify the maximum number of arrays that can be placed in each bucket, eg:

```
var maxLength = 32768;
var pool = ArrayPool<int>.Create(maxLength,1024);
var bufferLength = 32768;
```

`ArrayPool`'s code isn't complicated. You can check it [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.Buffers/src/System/Buffers)

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track.

The 16K iterations of your loop will be handled by a small number of threads.  If you capture a local variable outside the loop, then every iteration shares the same object.  If you declare a local and allocate an object inside the loop then each you will have 16K allocations.

There is an intermediate location where you can allocate an object, and it's called [Thread Local Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-parallel-for-loop-with-thread-local-variables).

It's intended primarilly for the scenario where you are accumulating a global result, but want to minimize the syncronization overhead.  So each Thread that runs iterations of your loop gets its own copy of the state, and then at the end you can aggregate them.

But using it reuse the a buffer across multiple loop iterations is fine too.